# occasionally I get a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in BindingsCollection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

Sometimes when I want to show a user control and set its bindings I get a  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. When I click on continue the action will be aborted, but when I do the same action again the user control is shown properly. I cannot reproduce the problem.

I've read some issues in which the BingdinsCollection is changed during the update. But I cannot point to a specific piece of code on my project. Can it have something to do with the window handle?

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingsCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBindings()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   .. my click
```

Comment: Your question would be improved if you asked something like "what is a process to debug this" or something like that rather than a yes/no question with very little information.

Comment: There isn't enough of a question here to help you. You need to post the failing code.

Comment: Seven years later, I get the same random nonsense exception coming from nowhere, only sometimes, with no further stack entries than some internal designer ones, and halting at Application.Run ... I feel you bro.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the BindingSource on another thread? Or doing **anything** on another thread that could cause the DataBindings collection to be changed while it's being enumerated?

From the framework source, that looks to be about the only way this could occur.

From Control.cs

```
 private void UpdateBindings()
    {
      for (int index = 0; index < this.DataBindings.Count; ++index)
        BindingContext.UpdateBinding(this.BindingContext, ((BindingsCollection) this.DataBindings)[index]);
    }
```

From BindingsCollection.cs

```
public Binding this[int index]
{
  get
  {
    return (Binding) this.List[index];
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding the bindings and showing the screen occurs in the same thread. The data itself comes from another thread. In the usercontrol where the exception occurs I do not remove bindings, only add them. I also don't know on which control the exception occurs, cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception stack trace, it looks like you are changing the visibility of the control, but the ArrayList bound to the control does not have the correct entry for the control.

I would try changing the order in which you are performing your actions. For example, if you are binding and then showing, I would reverse that process.

Comment: First I create the control, set the bindings and it to its parent and finally I show it. We only want to present actual data and not default/empty values. We use colors to show state and don't want to show a state change all the time.

Comment: Ok, it sounds like in some cases the binding is incorrect. I don't see the code that you are using, but I would ensure that there was plenty of range checking built in around the array list and the index that is used to bind the control.